# How can I create a montage of thousands of images more efficiently?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to create a single, very large image composed of thousands of 4x4 pixel images. I am using Rmagick's `montage` command for this.

```
mosaic = ImageList.new(*slices.map{ |slice| slice.image.filename })

mosaic = mosaic.montage {
  self.geometry = "256x256+0+0"
  self.tile     = "4096x"
}
```

Some info

- The resulting image is 32768x32768 px in size.
- The ImageList `mosaic` is composed of 16384 images, each 256x256 px each

The creation of the `ImageList`, loading all `Image` instances into memory, runs relatively quickly. The `montage` call is where things get very sluggish.

What is a more performant way of generating my final 32768x32768 px using the `mosaic` `ImageList` that is already in memory?

Comment: Seems like what you are describing is simply an expensive process.

Comment: Agreed. Being I'm not an ImageMagick expert by any means, I figured I'd ask if there is a proven faster approach that packing all the images into a single `montage` call!